# Why is $S = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid \text{$x$, $y$ even integers}\}$ not a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $S = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid \text{$x$, $y$ even integers}\} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$.

Why is this not a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$? $0$ seems to be in it ($2(0) = 0$), $x+y$ seems to be in it, and $kx$ where $k$ is an integer seems to be in it as well.

Thanks!

Comment: **When** $k$ **is an integer**; but what about the non-integer scalars?

Comment: But if you consider $\mathbb{R}^2$ has a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, however.

Comment: You need $k(x,y)\in S$ for all $(x,y)\in S$ and for all $k\in\mathbb R$.  The statement you give---that this holds when $k$ is an integer, is not enough.

Comment: @user110076 : for any vector space there is an associated _field_.  Most often people use the real numbers, sometimes people use the complex numbers, $\mathbb{F}_2$, or other fields.  If your field is $\mathbb{R}$, then $S$ must be closed under scalar multiplication, which it isn't (multiply $(1,0)$ by $1/2$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subspaces have to be closed under more general linear combinations than just $x + y$. That is, you have to have

$$
c_1 x + c_2 y \in S
$$
whenever $x,y \in S$ for any $c_1,c_2 \in \mathbb R$ (since the original vector space is a real-vector space, the scalars for linear combinations are, in general, real numbers)

Answer (score 2):

It is not a subspace of $\mathbb{ R}^2$ because $kx$ has to be in it for every real $k$, not just integer $k$.

Answer (score 0):

But $k$ must live in a field, and $\mathbb{Z}$ isn't.

Comment: In fact, $k$ has to be in the reals.